# Boost Process : How do I redirect process output to a file?

Tags: boost-process

Launching a process using the Boost::Process library, I have no problem reading output from stdout.  However, if I instead wanted to redirect stdout to a file, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: please use correct tags for your question

Comment: Do you need to capture both? If not you can start the child process with `' > filename '` appended to it to store output directly.

Comment: Not sure how I go about doing that with the boost::process library, Miltox.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing that you use boost.process 0.5 you would do it that way:

```
boost::iostream::file_descriptor_sink fl("my_file");
namespace bp = boost::process;

bp::child c = bp::execute(bp::set_cmd("ls"), bind_stdout(fl.handle()));
```

If you want to use boost.process 0.6 (which I'd recommend), you just write:

```
bp::child c("ls", bp::stdout > "my_file");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to build with Boost 1.78. Also the namespace for file_descriptor_sink apparently is `boost::iostreams`.